# Not able to upgrade my Ubuntu distribution

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, upgrade, ubuntu-10.10, apt-get

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid". I wanted to upgrade my distribution to 10.10.

When I performing th upgrade in Update Manager, I get an error message.

I have even tried to update via console as well. I am appending the log file which includes the details of that issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

I think `sources.list.distUpgrade` was corrupted.

#### `/var/log/Main.log`:

```
2011-08-28 16:59:33,085 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg']'
2011-08-28 16:59:33,086 INFO uname information: 'Linux gridlex-laptop 2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:09:46 UTC 2011 i686'
2011-08-28 16:59:33,087 INFO creating state file with '['tar', '-z', '-c', '-f', '/var/log/dist-upgrade/system_state.tar.gz', '/etc/apt/preferences.d/', '/etc/apt/sources.list', '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/', '/var/lib/dpkg/status']'
2011-08-28 16:59:33,382 INFO release-upgrader version '0.142.20' started
2011-08-28 16:59:33,386 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2011-08-28 16:59:33,425 DEBUG aufsOptionsAndEnvironmentSetup()
2011-08-28 16:59:33,427 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-rw-Aj6lHJ' as aufs_rw_dir
2011-08-28 16:59:33,427 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-chroot-p2eRqD' as aufs chroot dir
2011-08-28 16:59:33,428 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2011-08-28 16:59:33,537 DEBUG lsb-release: 'lucid'
2011-08-28 16:59:33,550 DEBUG who -m --ips: 'gridlex  pts/0        2011-08-28 16:21 (:0.0)
'
2011-08-28 16:59:33,552 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2011-08-28 16:59:33,568 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-28 16:59:34,017 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 30616
2011-08-28 16:59:34,018 DEBUG needServerMode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2011-08-28 16:59:34,018 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2011-08-28 16:59:34,019 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2011-08-28 16:59:41,227 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-28 16:59:41,627 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 30616
2011-08-28 16:59:41,627 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2011-08-28 16:59:41,628 DEBUG Plugin modules in ./plugins: deb_plugin.py dpkg_status_plugin.py kdelibs4to5_plugin.py langpack_manual_plugin.py remove_lilo_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,628 DEBUG Loading module ./plugins/deb_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,630 DEBUG Plugins in <module 'deb_plugin' from './plugins/deb_plugin.py'>: <class 'deb_plugin.DebPlugin'>
2011-08-28 16:59:41,630 DEBUG Loading module ./plugins/dpkg_status_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,633 DEBUG Plugins in <module 'dpkg_status_plugin' from './plugins/dpkg_status_plugin.py'>: <class 'dpkg_status_plugin.DpkgStatusPlugin'>
2011-08-28 16:59:41,634 DEBUG Loading module ./plugins/kdelibs4to5_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,642 DEBUG Plugins in <module 'kdelibs4to5_plugin' from './plugins/kdelibs4to5_plugin.py'>: <class 'kdelibs4to5_plugin.Kdelibs4devToKdelibs5devPlugin'>
2011-08-28 16:59:41,642 DEBUG Loading module ./plugins/langpack_manual_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,644 DEBUG Plugins in <module 'langpack_manual_plugin' from './plugins/langpack_manual_plugin.py'>: <class 'langpack_manual_plugin.MarkLangpacksManuallyInstalledPlugin'>
2011-08-28 16:59:41,644 DEBUG Loading module ./plugins/remove_lilo_plugin.py
2011-08-28 16:59:41,645 DEBUG Plugins in <module 'remove_lilo_plugin' from './plugins/remove_lilo_plugin.py'>: <class 'remove_lilo_plugin.RemoveLiloPlugin'>
2011-08-28 16:59:41,645 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2011-08-28 16:59:41,645 DEBUG plugins for condition 'maverickPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2011-08-28 16:59:41,645 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_lucidPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,880 DEBUG Foreign: google-talkplugin google-chrome-stable skype acroread adobeair
2011-08-28 16:59:45,880 DEBUG Obsolete: firefox-locale-en teamviewer6 language-support-translations-en nautilus-dropbox equinox-theme gtk2-engines-equinox linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic lucidor xul-ext-ubufox yammer
2011-08-28 16:59:45,881 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2011-08-28 16:59:45,946 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList()
2011-08-28 16:59:45,949 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,949 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,950 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,951 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG entry 'deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,952 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,953 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,954 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,955 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner #Added by software-center'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,955 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner #Added by software-center' is already set to new dist
2011-08-28 16:59:45,955 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,959 DEBUG entry '# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to maverick' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2011-08-28 16:59:45,959 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main'
2011-08-28 16:59:45,963 DEBUG entry '# deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to maverick' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2011-08-28 16:59:45,994 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2011-08-28 17:00:43,609 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-28 17:00:43,609 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2011-08-28 17:00:47,427 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 32521
2011-08-28 17:00:47,427 DEBUG needServerMode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2011-08-28 17:02:09,560 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
2011-08-28 17:02:09,561 DEBUG abort called
2011-08-28 17:02:09,568 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-28 17:02:09,568 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked) 
2011-08-28 17:02:12,205 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 30616
2011-08-28 17:02:12,205 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download and burn the ISO for [10.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/).  Then boot off the image and do an inplace upgrade.